# Analogue of GenerateViewID for Animator objects?

Tags: android, xml, android-resources, objectanimator

I have a custom ObjectAnimator object, created at runtime.  Is there something similar to View's generateViewID() method that lets me get an id for it so I can attach it to a FragmentTransaction?  In other words, I want to do something like this:

```
// assuming I already have ObjectAnimator objects animator1 and animator2
// also already have a FragmentTransaction object named transaction.

int id1 = animator1.generateID();
int id2 = animator2.generateID();
transaction.setCustomAnimations(id1, id2);
```

Comment: AFAIK, those have to be actual animation resources.

Comment: override Fragment.onCreateAnimator